# Batch file to add printers across domains without trust

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, scripting, network-printers

I work in an environment with two domains. A lab domain (offline) and a production domain (online). the lab network sits in a DMZ and is NAT'd to the production domain. There is no AD trust between the two domains.

There are printers that I manage on the lab domain that I want accessible from the production domain. I want users on the production domain to be able to run a batch file to add these printers onto production computers (I cannot deploy using GPO for various reasons).

I'm aware of two methods of adding printers using the command line:

```
START \\printserver\printer
```

&

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\printserver\printer
```

Both of these methods work after authenticating to the lab domain. What I want to do is pass credentials and authenticate within the context of the batch file instead of Windows prompting the user. I want to do this to avoid the confusion users have with authenticating across domains (productionDomain\user / labDomain\user). Runas doesn't work because the production domain is unaware of lab domain credentials.

I want to do something like:

```
@echo off
set loc=\\printserverip\
set p1=printername1
set p2=printername2
set p3=printername3
set p4=printername4
set /P id=Enter LABDOMAIN Login: %=%
powershell -Command $pw = read-host "Enter LABDOMAIN password" -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pw) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt & set /p pwd=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt

REM ---AUTHENTICATE OR RUN THE FOLLOWING IN THE CONTEXT OF THE CREDENTIALS ABOVE---

START %loc%%p1%
START %loc%%p2%
START %loc%%p3%
START %loc%%p4%

REM ---OR---

RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /in /n%loc%%p1%
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /in /n%loc%%p2%
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /in /n%loc%%p3%
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /in /n%loc%%p4%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work...

```
NET USE \\printserverip /USER:%id% %pwd%
```

Add it right before this section:

```
START %loc%%p1%
START %loc%%p2%
START %loc%%p3%
START %loc%%p4%
```

Comment: I ended up enabling anonymous printing to solve my problem, but this solution works.